# Converting a shell script to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, migration, sh

After switching an application from Linux to Windows, I need to convert a shell script to a Windows equivalent. My choices were basically batch and PowerShell and I decided to give a shot to PowerShell.

For anyone interested, it's a local check for Check_MK to get information about SoftEther installed version and the number of sessions with performance data.

The initial shell script was as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd=$(/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd localhost:port /server /password:password /in:/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local/vpncmd.txt)
version=$(echo "$cmd" | head -4 | tail -1)
sessions=$(echo "$cmd" | grep Sessions | awk '$1=$1' | cut -c21-22)

if [ -z "$version" ]; then
 echo "3 VPN_Version - Can't get the information from vpncmd"
else
 echo "0 VPN_Version - SoftEther VPN Server $version"
fi

if [ -z "$sessions" ]; then
 echo "3 VPN_Sessions - Can't get the information from vpncmd"
else
 echo "P VPN_Sessions sessions=$sessions;2;2"
fi
```

I basically got everything working except the 2 hardest lines of code:

```bsh
cd "C:\Program Files\SoftEther VPN Server"
$cmd = vpncmd localhost:port /server /password:password /in:vpncmd.txt
$version=
$sessions=

if($version -eq $null) {
    echo "3 VPN_Version - Can't get the information from vpncmd"
} else {
    echo "0 VPN_Version - SoftEther VPN Server $version"
}

if($sessions -eq $null) {
    echo "3 VPN_Sessions - Can't get the information from vpncmd"
} else {
    echo "P VPN_Sessions sessions=$sessions;2;2"
}
```

I need help with going from the `head`, `tail`, `grep`, `awk` and `cut` one liners to whatever is equivalent in PowerShell. I read about `Get-Content` but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to do this and would like to prevent going from 1 line definition to 10 lines if that's possible to be as efficient in PowerShell.

Sample output of `vpncmd`'s output: https://pastebin.com/J5FcHzHK

Comment: it seems you want to pare the output of an exe ... so, please post the text in your `$cmd` variable.

Comment: For the first line `echo "$cmd" | head -4 | tail -1`, lets says you've a string array that is sent to the pipeline: `Invoke-Expression "your command" | Select-Object -first 4 | Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, the executable outputs hundreds of rows of information, the `grep` part allows me to get the only row with the word `Sessions`, while the version is always on the 3rd line, hence the `head -4 | tail -1`.

Comment: @Moerwald It's not an array, just rows of text, I should have specified. I added an example output. https://pastebin.com/J5FcHzHK

Comment: Just edited that pastebin link, a part was missing. If you CTRL+F `Sessions` it's there once at the end.

Comment: @dnLL - thank you for posting the sample data. [*grin*] is that one multiline string **_when it is stored in `$cmd` in powershell_** OR an array of strings?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Is it stored as is in $cmd, should just be a string with line returns, really, unless PowerShell has some built-in conversion to make it an array of strings.

Comment: @dnLL - PoSh will grab the output at a multiline string if the whole string is output at once. if it is output one-line-at-a-time, then you will get an array of strings. ///// so, what do you see in the `$cmd` variable in PoSh when you do `$cmd.Count` or `$cmd.GetType()`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I get a count of 433 and `System.Array` as a base type. My PasteBin probably has some duplicates since it has more lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the data being an array of lines & the word `Version` appearing multiple times in the actual source, the code needs to change a tad. in this version, it uses the way that `-match` works on an array to give the whole line as a result. that requires working on the output line to parse the desired data.

```
$Version = ($Vpncmd_Output -match '^Version \d{1,}\.\d{1,}' -split 'Version ' )[-1].Trim()
$SessionCount = [int]($Vpncmd_Output -match 'Number of Sessions\s+\|').Split('|')[-1].Trim()

$Version
$SessionCount
```

output ...

```
4.29 Build 9680   (English)
0
```

<s>using the data in your PasteBin post, and presuming that is a multiline string, not an array of strings, this seems to work [*grin*] ...</s>

```
$Vpncmd_Output -match '(?m)Number of Sessions\s+\|(?<Sessions>.*)'
$Matches.Sessions
# output = 0
$Vpncmd_Output -match '(?m)Version (?<Version>.+)'
$Matches.Version
# output = 4.29 Build 9680   (English)
```

i tried to combine the regex into one, but failed. [*blush*] the way i have it requires two passes, but it does work.

Comment: Turns out it's probably an array of strings. I still tried to match the version with your expression and here is what I'm getting: https://imgur.com/a/NZoeOjJ

Comment: The word "version" is sadly there multiple times, hence why I was using shell to get the 3rd line instead. I guess it's even easier now that I know that it's an array.

Comment: The session part is working, except that it returns the full line rather than just the number at the end of the line. I was using `cut` in shell. I think I can figure out the rest from what you have provided, thank you for your help!! @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @dnLL - ah! i managed to miss your response earlier on string array or multiline string. [*blush*] is `Version` only at the start of the line when the number is there?

Comment: If you mean Session, the line is always `Number of Sessions                            |0` with the number at the end (it's always the same number of spaces too, StackOverflow removes them but you can see in the PasteBin). If you mean Version, I'm really just looking for that 3rd line... `Version 4.29 Build 9680   (English)`. But it's there multiple times in the output.

Comment: @dnLL - i am talking about `Version`. try the rewritten code i posted. i haven't tested it with multiple `Version` lines, but once you have the output of the `-match` you otta be able to deal with the resulting collection of [probably] identical strings. [*grin*]

Comment: Works perfectly for Version. For Sessions it says Split is not found.

Comment: @dnLL - try that line _without_ the stuff outside of the `()`. i suspect you will have an array of multiple lines. if that is so, then you can put a `[0]` between the 1st `)` and the `.Split()` so that you are acting on just one line.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly with the `[0]`. Not sure why it returns multiple lines considering there is only one match?

Comment: @dnLL - you said there were multiple matches for the word `Version`, so that is why you are getting multiple items from the `-match`. it's the somewhat weird way that PoSh handles the `-match` operator when the left hand side is a collection - you DO NOT get anything in the `$Matches` automatic $Var - instead, you get the array items that match the regex.

Comment: Except the issue was with Sessions and there is only one match there. I don't have the issue with Version despite the multiple match, probably because we're using `- split` instead of `.split()`. Sorry if this is all confusing, at the end of the day it's working although I'm not sure why. I will try some more tests later today.

Comment: @dnLL - arg! that is confusing ... sorry about the cross-communication ... and i am glad that you worked it out. [*grin*]

Comment: So after further tests, $version is a string but it seems to be because of the `[-1].Trim()` since without it it's an array with 6 strings. As for $sessions, it's an array with 1 string only since there is only one result for the match.

I'm not shocked about $sessions being an array (despite having only 1 match) since $cmd is an array anyway. But I'm surprised that $version isn't after that [-1].Trim() command.

Comment: @dnLL - without seeing the whole shebang of the data set ... i can't even guess. [*grin*] the important thing is that you have a way to get the strings - and once you have those, you can slice-n-dice them into what you need.

Comment: Also, I don't think the integer cast is relevant here since the result goes back into another string anyway.